# Where are API docs for Nest Camera?

Tags: camera, nest-api

I have looked all through the Nest developers site, and I can't find anything related to the camera.  I can find plenty of great information on the thermostat and the smoke / CO alarm, but nothing for the camera.

In particular, I'm looking for how to get the video URL, how to get/set video resolution and frame rate, and how to get/set the zoom level (if applicable).  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a short update to this question: I believe Nest made an API for the camera available today: https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api-reference/overview#cameras

Comment: That's correct, the Nest Cam API launched today. You can use it much like you used the API for the other Nest products. You can see an official sample that uses it at https://github.com/nestlabs/rest-streaming

Answer (score 3):

There are no Nest Cam API's at the moment. However, we're hearing feedback asking for them. I'd love to hear what you would use them for.

Comment: I am a senior engineer with CrowdOptic.com, one of Google's certified development partners. We live stream from Google glass to audiences around the world and would like to see if we could make a use case that utilizes both Nest Cam, Google glass, and our patented Clustering technology to integrate streams from both Glass and Nest Cam.

Comment: Very interesting. The only live streams that are available are through public streams. The streams can be viewed in a browser, but thats it.

Comment: @urman Is there anyway to control the recording of camera through a web application and access recorded data from the cloud using a API?

Comment: Camera api's don't exist just yet. And just like the other apis it probably will not include historical data.

Comment: An API exists now (see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32897301/3625228 ) but it seems, as @urman suspected, it is sort of limited. A first step though.

Comment: I'm basically clairvoyant. Fortune anyone?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the Dropcam (Nest camera) API is still in Beta.  You can sign up for the beta [here](http://support.dropcam.com/entries/73330006-Dropcam-API-Beta).

Comment: Unfortunately, the link on that page doesn't work any more.  I can't find any current information about the beta program or any way to sign up.  It doesn't look like the beta program is still active.  I sent a contact us message to Nest to ask them about it.